# Gradient not displaying correctly in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, gradient, microsoft-edge

There is an ADOBE illustrator generated gradient and the CSS code is as below:

```
.firs{
    background: #4B79A1;
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(.....) 100%);
    background : -webkit-linear-gradient(.....) 100%);
    background : -webkit-gradient(....),color-stop(.....) ));
    background : -o-linear-gradient(.....) 0%, rgba(......) 0%, rgba(......) 25.17%, rgba(.........) 50.5%, rgba(.......) 75.17%, rgba(.......) 100%);
    background : -ms-linear-gradient(........) 0%, rgba(........) 0%, rgba(.........., 1) 25.17%, rgba(............., 1) 50.5%, rgba(..........., 1) 75.17%, rgba(............., 1) 100%);
}
```

the gradient CSS runs smoothly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Edge, it becomes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt0Ym.png).

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share the related html and css style code, so that we could test it on our side? Besides, when you test the sample in the chrome or Firefox browser, it is better to capture a screenshot and post it, it might be easier for us to know what you want.

Comment: I have posted the image above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your rgba() function. By convention rgb is the mixture or color
    panel of red-green-blue colors to produce different type of color. But a(alpha) is
    used to optimize the color visualization. 1 is set to true which 100% or visible, 0 
    is set to false which is invisible.

As I can see in your code, `-ms-linear-gradient(......., 1).` You need to understand that 
    `linear-gradient()` function uses top-down, left-right, right-left or bottom-up
    approaches. In your case, you are using top-down approach. But the problem is you are
    using 100% opacity with edge and you cannot get the gradient correctly.

Try to optimize your linear function with something like this: 
    `-ms-linear-gradient(......., 0.5)` or `-ms-linear-gradient(......., 0.45)` which is 
    literally translated as 50% or 45% alpha linear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try code from [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)?
I think code like below should works

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(...) 0%, rgba(...) 50%, rgba(...) 51%, rgba(...) 100%)
```